# Radio button list in Ruby on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Just trying to show grouped radio buttons on a page and get a selected value on post request.

```
    %h2 Choose your delivery type

    -DeliveryType.all.each do |dt|
      %p
        =radio_button_tag "delivery_type", dt.name, false
        =label_tag "delivery_type_#{dt.id}", dt.name

    %p= button_to "Forward", delivery_type_create_path


 def delivery_type_create
    #params[:delivery_type] is nil
  end
```

I debugged

```
pp params
{"authenticity_token"=>"DwDYHY/mm1WEMBXZuHAN+4fqksojTHZVwuTob8LxDvA=",
 "action"=>"delivery_type_create",
 "controller"=>"orders"}
```

I tried this

```
%h2 Choose your delivery type
-form_tag do
  -DeliveryType.all.each do |dt|
    %p
      =radio_button_tag "delivery_type", dt.name, false
      =label_tag "delivery_type_#{dt.id}", dt.name
  %p= button_to "Forward", delivery_type_create_path
```

but it does not show itself at all, only h2 and the another part of a page are shown.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `= form_tag`, not `- form_tag`.